# Detect WebP files

Tags: ubuntu, images, image-manipulation

I am using Ubuntu and `type` doesn't seem to work for webp images:

> bash: type: test.webp: not found

How can I discriminate webp images from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

The command `file` is what you're looking for.

Output for me:

```
image.webp: RIFF (little-endian) data, Web/P image, VP8 encoding, 320x241, Scaling: [none]x[none], YUV color, decoders should clamp
```

The version here is the one is from http://darwinsys.com/file/ and in the default software repositories of most distributions, including Ubuntu (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/file) where it's installed per default on the desktop flavor (http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.manifest → `file 1:5.25-2ubuntu1`).

Comment: I just get `RIFF (little-endian) data`.

Comment: What version of `file` do you have, what does `file -v` say?
What I posted is from `5.25`.

Comment: Also the magic file used has it in it, in my case I can check it with `grep -i webp /usr/share/misc/magic`. Not sure whether the path is the same on Ubuntu.